# How do I put a \n into a property file's value?

Tags: java, properties

I'm using Java Property files and would like to have a newline character put into a value (used as the contents of a message to the user), so that this output contains a new line.

I tried putting it in as a \\n (as I have to escape the backslash character), but I just end up with a message with \n written in it.

ie.

```
message=Dear Foo,\\n\\nThank you for signing up for Bar.
```

gives:

```
Dear Foo,\n\nThank you for signing up for Bar.
```

I want:

```
Dear Foo,

Thank you for signing up for Bar.
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: \ escapes the \ character. Try use using one \

Comment: yeah I caught it, but apparently not before anybody else saw it. Doh.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply use `\n` for this purpose

You are escaping the escape character using `\\` hence you are getting `\n` printed

Comment: I did that because I was under the impression that Properties will remove the \ character. I wanted it to be preserved for when it goes into the string.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
message=Dear Foo,\nThank you for signing up for Bar.
```